# Scipy - netcdf - data types not writing and getting weird numbers

Tags: python, scipy, netcdf

I am trying to write a netcdf file using scipy.
I've copied the example from the scipy website - but when I look at the output, I am getting weird numbers.

I've been trying this for other things as well, and even specifying .astype(np.float32) for another variable that I declared as 'float32'.

Python code:

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
from scipy.io import netcdf
f = netcdf.netcdf_file('simple.nc', 'w')
f.history = 'Created for a test'
f.createDimension('time', 10)
time = f.createVariable('time', 'i', ('time',))
time[:] = np.arange(10)
time.units = 'days since 2008-01-01'
f.close()
```

Output:

```
ncdump -v time simple.nc 
netcdf simple {
dimensions:
    time = 10 ;
variables:
    int time(time) ;
        time:units = "days since 2008-01-01" ;

// global attributes:
    :history = "Created for a test" ;
data:

 time = 0, 16777216, 33554432, 50331648, 67108864, 83886080, 100663296, 
    117440512, 134217728, 150994944 ;
}
```

Comment: What OS and version of scipy are you using? I'm not able to reproduce this problem on Ubuntu, with scipy version 0.9.0 nor 0.12.0.

Comment: It seems if I use 'import Scientific.IO.NetCDF as NetCDF' instead of from 'scipy.io import netcdf' - I am able to use a double and get something reasonable. Not sure if it'll give me more data type issues later.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in Scipy 0.11.0, which was fixed in 0.12.0
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/d2b5014

Answer (score 1):

I think my problem was using scipy.io instead of Scientific.IO

This page suggests that scipy.io is only for reading and Scientific.IO is for reading and writing. I had to use data type double though.
http://www-pord.ucsd.edu/~cjiang/python.html

Python Code:

```
from Scientific.IO.NetCDF import NetCDFFile
import numpy as np

f = NetCDFFile('simple.nc', 'w')
f.history = 'Created for a test'
f.createDimension('time', 10)
time = f.createVariable('time', 'd', ('time',))
time[:] = np.arange(10)
time.units = 'days since 2008-01-01'
f.close()
```

Output:

```
ncdump -v time simple.nc 
netcdf simple {
dimensions:
    time = 10 ;
variables:
double time(time) ;
    time:units = "days since 2008-01-01" ;

// global attributes:
    :history = "Created for a test" ;
data:

 time = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, just a comment:

The problem appears to be  involve the endianness of the data type:

```
In [23]: x = np.arange(10)
In [30]: x.view('>i4')
Out[30]: 
array([        0,  16777216,  33554432,  50331648,  67108864,  83886080,
       100663296, 117440512, 134217728, 150994944])
```

Comment: I'm using OS 10.8.2 and scipy version 0.11.0.